# How to improve the performance of document.getElementByName when needed repeatedly

Tags: javascript, performance, dom

I have a JavaScript function that is supposed to add a template to the page and fill it in with values. The performance is crippling when I have over 500 items to add. I suspect that it is because for each element that is added, my `document.getElementsByName` call gets slower.

Here is what I have:

```
function addAllItems() {
    var items = $("#existingItems")[0];
    var addCount = 0;
    var default_item_type = document.getElementsByName("existingItems[''].model.itemType")[0].value;
    var default_item_name = document.getElementsByName("existingItems[''].model.itemName")[0].value;
    var default_item_code = document.getElementsByName("existingItems[''].model.itemCode")[0].value;
    var default_fail = document.getElementsByName("existingItems[''].model.itemFail")[0].checked;
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        if(!itemArray.includes(items[i].text)) {
            $(".addLine").click();
            var name = "newItems["+addCount+"].model"
            document.getElementsByName(name+".itemAFF")[0].value=items[i].text;
            document.getElementsByName(name+".itemType")[0].value=default_item_type;
            document.getElementsByName(name+".itemName")[0].value=default_item_name;
            document.getElementsByName(name+".itemCode")[0].value=default_item_code;
            document.getElementsByName(name+".itemFail")[0].checked=default_fail;
            addCount++;
        }
    }
}
```

What this is supposed to do is fill out a template of items with default values. How can I reduce the amount of DOM class in my for loop? Since I am adding the templates on the fly, I am not sure how I can cache them. I was thinking about adding just the templates first and saving each added template element into an array and then go through the array and fill it out, but I am not sure how to do it right since I still need to get the element by doing a DOM call.

Any help, suggestions, feedback is appreciated.

Comment: What does `$(".addLine").click();` do? Are you adding a blank line and then using `.getElementsByName()` to search for the blank line's fields to populate it? Why don't you update the function that creates the fields to set the values at that time?

Comment: Do these elements have ids?

Comment: @nnnnnn it adds a line with blank fields. I need to leave them blank though because it is possible to put in custom values instead of inheriting defaults.

Comment: @JonSG they do not have IDs. Is it possible to assign something a unique ID as it is created? If I gave them a unique ID, wouldn't I still need to use document.getElementById to find it again?

Comment: Yes, you would use **getElementById()**, but this might be faster for a number of reasons.  Firstly, elements with ids may be natively indexed and/or already a direct child of the window object.  Secondly, given that the result is singular your code does not have to deal with the array part and the native method can stop searching (using whatever method it uses) for matches.